# Google Sheets - Match 3 conditions with Minus, CONCATENATE and SUM

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I want to use `SUM` to calculate from seconds row until before the current row.

[image]

[image: But I get an error with must be a range]

But I get an error with **must be a range**

I want an expected result is **C17**

Code:

```
SUM(C7:CONCATENATE("C", MINUS(row(),1)))
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C7:"&CONCATENATE("C", MINUS(ROW(), 1))))
```

or:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C7:C"&ROW()-1))
```

or:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(C7), 3, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, 3, 4)))
```